# prepare( for segue:) not being called on segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have uploaded the project here as I feel that code snippets are not enough to understand the issue.

I have two TableViewControllers, both of which segue to an additional TableViewController. All segues are set to Show, and all segues have identifiers. Each TableViewController class also has its own `prepare(for segue:, sender: Any?` function defined. The segues in both View Controllers is set to a BarButtonItem, so when the BarButtonItem is tapped, the segue is run. I've put some print statements in my code in both `prepare` functions, and I can see that `prepare` is only called when a segue occurs from my `ChecklistViewController` TableViewController, and not from my `ListViewController` TableViewController.

If you look at Main.storyboard in the project I linked, `ListViewController` is the leftmost view controller, below the Navigation Controller. The BarButtonItem in the upper right is linked to a segue with identifier `NewList`, but that identifier does not get run when the button is tapped.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you associated the right class to the view controller in storyboard and made sure that you do not have any spelling mistakes with the identifiers of the segues?

By the way, I was not able to download your project. My Anti-Virus program warned me that there is a virus-infected file in this archive.
Could you provide some code snippets and/or screenshots directly here?

Comment: Turns out I didn't associate the right class with the view controller in question. Thanks for your help!